# While loop failing to respect conditions

Tags: r, while-loop

I have a data frame containing a set of texts, each with a word count. It looks a bit like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Items = sample(1:495, 495, replace = FALSE), Length.in.words = sample(380:820, 495, replace = TRUE))
```

I need to assign these texts to judges. There are several parameters for this assignment. The first is that each text should be seen by three judges. So I've duplicated the original dataframe twice, so that each text is now represented three times:

```
df2 <- df1
df3 <- df1
df <- rbind(df1, df2, df3)
```

Next, I've written a small function to assign the texts to the judges. It uses tidyverse and groupdata2:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(groupdata2)

sample_scripts <- function(x, judges){

all <- fold(x, num_col = "Length.in.words", k = judges)
  judge_list <- split(all, all$.folds)
  while (TRUE %in% lapply(X = judge_list, FUN = duplicated)){
    all <- fold(all, num_col = "Length.in.words", k = judges)
    judge_list <- split(all, all$.folds)
  }

  assign("judge_list", judge_list, envir = globalenv())
}
```

The function does a couple of things. It uses `groupdata2::fold` to balance each judge's texts in terms of word count. And, at least in theory, it uses `while` to iterate until each judge's list of texts contains no duplicates. The judges must not see the same text twice! I run the function like this:

```
sample_scripts(df, 33)
```

But the "while" loop is not working as intended - each time I run the function, I get duplicates in several of the judge's lists of texts. I test it like this:

```
lapply(X = judge_list, FUN = duplicated)
```

Can anyone help me to fix this, so that the while loop iterates the text assignment until there are no duplicates in any judge list?

Thanks

Peter

Comment: What is your desired output (based on your given input)?

Comment: The "judge_list" object. At the end of the actual function, there is a line which outputs it to the global environment.

Comment: But how should it look like? Perhaps there are more direct ways to solve your issue.

Comment: I need two objects. One is the judge_list, which in reality contains not only the text numbers and word counts, but several additional columns of data that may need to be analysed later. The second item is a simple data frame with 33 columns (each corresponding to a judge), and the text numbers of the texts assigned to them (the code for creating this is not in the example above). And again, the constraints I've noted above must be respected: (1) each text seen by three different judges, (2) each judge's list having texts of a similar length, (3) no judge seeing any single text more than once.

Comment: It might simplify to leave df as list of three rather than `rbind(` them.

Answer (score 2):

Solution out of left field here. I think this might be considered an NP-hard problem, but as I read it, it strikes me as a constrained discrete optimization problem - make assignments to minimize the variance in the number of pages assigned to each judge, with three judges assigned to each item and making sure no judge is assigned the same item twice.

It takes awhile to run but here's a probabilistic solution using the genetic algorithm

```
library(GA)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- data.frame(
  Items = sample(1:495, 495, replace = FALSE), 
  Length.in.words = sample(380:820, 495, replace = TRUE)
)


sample_scripts <- function(x, judges){
  
  decode <- function(encX) {
    # enumerate the three judges assigned to each text
    judgesAssign <- floor(encX) |> 
      split(seq_along(x$Items))
    
    # check for duplicates
    dups <- map_lgl(judgesAssign, \(.x) any(duplicated(.x))) |> sum()
    
    list(judgesAssign = judgesAssign, dups = dups)
  }
  
  fitness <- function(encX) {
    
    decX <- decode(encX)
    
    # enumerate the texts assigned to each judge
    itemAssign <- decX$judgesAssign |> 
      as_tibble() |> 
      pivot_longer(
        everything(), 
        names_to = "Items",
        values_to = "judge"
      ) |> 
      # match types in df
      mutate(Items = as.integer(Items))
    
    # determine words and items assigned to each count
    assignCounts <-  itemAssign|> 
      left_join(x, by = "Items") |> 
      # ensure every judge is represented
      bind_rows(
        tibble(judge = seq(judges), Length.in.words = 0)
      ) |> 
      group_by(judge) |> 
      # subtract 1 for empty row
      summarise(n_words = sum(Length.in.words), n_items = n() - 1)
    
    # minimize variance
    f <- -(var(assignCounts$n_words)/mean(assignCounts$n_words) + 
             var(assignCounts$n_items)/mean(assignCounts$n_items))
    
    # penalty term for duplicates
    pen <- sqrt(.Machine$double.xmax)
    dupPen <- decX$dups*pen
    
    # fitness function minimizes variance and heavy penalty for duplicates
    f - dupPen
    
  }
  
  scriptCt <- NROW(x)
  
  GA <- ga(
    "real-valued",
    fitness = fitness,
    lower = rep(1, scriptCt*3), upper = rep(judges, scriptCt*3) + 1,
    maxiter = 750, run = 200, seed = 123, pmutation = 0.25,
    suggestions = sample(seq(judges), 3*scriptCt, TRUE),
    maxFitness = 0
  )

  decSol <- decode(GA@solution[1, ])
  finalAssignments <- decSol$judgesAssign |>
    as_tibble() |>
    pivot_longer(
      everything(),
      names_to = "Items",
      values_to = "judge"
    ) |>
    # match types in df
    mutate(Items = as.integer(Items))
  
  list(
    gaRslt = GA,
    fitness = fitness_tot(GA@solution),
    decodedSol = decSol,
    assignmentsByJudge = split(finalAssignments$Items, finalAssignments$judge),
    assignmentsByItem = decSol$judgesAssign,
    anyDuplicates = decSol$dups
  )

}

sample_scripts(df1, 33)
```

It does not ensure each judge is every judge has the same number of `Items`, but it optimizes to keep the number relatively the same. When I ran it, most judges had between 45 and 55 items, but there were long tails. I didn't have any success trying to constrain it to all have 45. You can play around with some of the parameters to `ga` that may help, but I imagine the solution space has a lot of local minima so might be difficult.

If you have the option to manually adjust, you could use this as a starting point and just take some of the items from the judges with a lot and assign them to the ones with hardly any. Not a global optimum, but likely pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to recode your `sample_scripts` function using only `base` R functions:

```r
sample_scripts <- function(data, n_judges = 33, n_judge_per_item = 3) {

  # Default-Values: 
  # 33 Judges
  # each Item has to be revised by 3 judges
  
  # initialize output
  judges_list <- lapply(seq_len(n_judges), 
                        \(n) data.frame(
                            Item = integer(0),
                            Length.in.words = integer(0)
                            )
                        )

  # Check if a judge is still available  
  free_judge <- rep(TRUE, n_judges)
  
  # target_length tries to distribute the text sizes
  target_length <- n_judge_per_item * sum(data$Length.in.words) / n_judges 

  # loop over items data.frame
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(data))) {
    # randomly pick three free judges
    samp_judge <- sample(seq_len(n_judges)[free_judge], size = n_judge_per_item)
    
    # assign items to judge
    for (j in samp_judge) {
      judges_list[[j]] <- 
        rbind(
          judges_list[[j]],
          data.frame(Item = data[["Items"]][i],
                     Length.in.words = data[["Length.in.words"]][i])
          )
      
      # check if judge is still available
      free_judge[j] <- (sum(judges_list[[j]][["Length.in.words"]]) < target_length)
        
    }
  }
  
  # return list
  judges_list
}
```

Your input just needs to be `df1` instead of `df <- rbind(df1, df1, df1)`. In this case `sample_scripts(df1)` returns for example

```r
[[14]]
   Item Length.in.words
1    12             817
2   245             389
3   372             649
4   413             731
5   329             698
6   193             492
7   405             731
8   376             593
9   297             539
10  356             774
11  125             492
12  359             716
13  472             611
14  128             397
[...]
```

Replacing the `data.frame`s by `tibble`s returns

```r
[[1]]
# A tibble: 42 × 2
    Item Length.in.words
   <int>           <int>
 1    99             738
 2    15             483
 3   341             763
 4   333             702
 5   407             797
 6   376             593
 7   356             774
 8     4             535
 9    53             739
10   354             570
# … with 32 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

[[2]]
# A tibble: 47 × 2
    Item Length.in.words
   <int>           <int>
 1    86             770
 2   404             550
 3   357             675
 4   331             431
 5   116             589
 6   438             554
 7   459             497
 8   319             651
 9    97             718
10    85             510
# … with 37 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
[...]
```

Your check for duplicates `lapply(X = judge_list, duplicated)` still gives us

```r
[[1]]
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[18] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[35] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[2]]
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[18] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[35] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

By using `unlist(lapply(X = judge_list, \(x) sum(x$Length.in.words)))` you can check if every judge has a similar amount of words.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. But after running the code, I realised that there is one constraint that was not clear in my explanation - all of the judges need to have the same number of texts (45). Is there a way to add this constraint? I thought perhaps judges could be removed from the "free judges" list when they hit 45; but I'm in over my head - I don't know how to code that without upsetting the rest of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for the suggestions. The constraint regarding the same number of items per judge is strict (I clearly should have mentioned it) - stricter than the constraint on minimizing the average length per text for each judge. I wrote the following, which uses the "greedy" method of grouping items to ensure that there are no duplicates within each judge's list, gives 45 items to each judge, and makes sure that each item is seen by exactly three judges. It doesn't manage the average length of the items, but it randomises the item lists prior to assignment, so I can just re-run the process a few times until I'm happy that the range is low enough.

```
sample_scripts <- function(x, texts_per_judge){
  x1 <- x
  x1 <- x1[sample(1:nrow(x1)), ]
  x2 <- x
  x2 <- x2[sample(1:nrow(x2)), ]
  x3 <- x
  x3 <- x3[sample(1:nrow(x3)), ]
  all <- rbind(x1, x2, x3)
  all <- group(all, method = "greedy", n = texts_per_judge)
  judge_list <- split(all, all$.groups)
  assign("judge_mean_length", value = aggregate(Length.in.words ~ .groups, data = judge_df, FUN = "mean"), envir = globalenv())
  assign("judge_list", judge_list, envir = globalenv())
}
```

I'm pretty satisfied with this solution but I'd still love to hear if anyone can come up with a solution that doesn't require re-running the process until the range in mean text length is manageable.